# how to download videos that require age verification with pytube?

Tags: python, dataset, pytube

I download and clip some youtube videos with pytube but some videos are not downloading and asking for age verification. How can I solve this? Thanks for your advice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python youtube\_dl does not allow to download age-restricted videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73088233/python-youtube-dl-does-not-allow-to-download-age-restricted-videos)

Comment: I was using pytube but I will change it according to your advice and I will share the update. thank you @Gameplay

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For pytube 15.0.0 I had the **AgeRestrictedError** in streams contents even using the use_oauth option.

I fixed the problem only changing ANDROID_MUSIC with ANDROID as "client" at line 223 of innertube.py:

```
def __init__(self, client='ANDROID_MUSIC', use_oauth=False, allow_cache=True): 

def __init__(self, client='ANDROID', use_oauth=False, allow_cache=True):
```

Comment: Why is this happening though? How did you know to look here?

Comment: Thanks for the fix, weird that it's such a trivial fix for what seems like should be more complicated.

Comment: Based on the solution above, I solved my problem in the following way, without needing to modify the source code:

from pytube import YouTube
from pytube.innertube import _default_clients

_default_clients["ANDROID_MUSIC"] = _default_clients["ANDROID"]
extractYB = YouTube(source_url)

video_stream = extractYB.streams.get_highest_resolution()
destination_path = './video/youtube'
video_stream.download(output_path=destination_path)
video_size_bytes = video_stream.filesize
video_duration_seconds = extractYB.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html):

> For advanced use cases, you can provide some additional arguments when you create a YouTube object:
>
> ```
> >>> yt = YouTube(
>         'http://youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo',
>         on_progress_callback=progress_func,
>         on_complete_callback=complete_func,
>         proxies=my_proxies,
>         use_oauth=False,
>         allow_oauth_cache=True
>     )
> ```
>
> ***The use_oauth and allow_oauth_cache flags allow you to authorize pytube to interact with YouTube using your account, and can be used to bypass age restrictions or access private videos and playlists.*** If allow_oauth_cache is set to True, you should only be prompted to do so once, after which point pytube will cache the tokens it needs to act on your behalf. Otherwise, you will be prompted again for each action that requires you to be authenticated.

So, in other words, something like this should work:

```
yt = YouTube(
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3eAMGXFw1o',
        use_oauth=True,
        allow_oauth_cache=True
    )
# then download the video in whichever way you choose fit
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution [@GTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76780768/4895962), I solved my problem in the following way, without needing to modify the source code:

```
# pytube==15.0.0
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube.innertube import _default_clients

_default_clients["ANDROID_MUSIC"] = _default_clients["ANDROID"]
extractYB = YouTube(source_url)


video_stream = extractYB.streams.get_highest_resolution()
destination_path = './video/youtube'
video_stream.download(output_path=destination_path)
video_size_bytes = video_stream.filesize
video_duration_seconds = extractYB.length
```

Comment: This results in 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is small and do not have dependency constraint. Try to use pytube 12.0.0 as a fix. Because it avoid change of pytube source code.