# i have problems with pytube and telegram bot

Tags: python, pytube, py-telegram-bot-api

I have a telegram bot that downloads videos from youtube.
i have 2 problems.

1. I used the pytube library to create the bot. shows age limit error while downloading some videos. How to avoid this.
   I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75791765/how-to-download-videos-that-require-age-verification-with-pytube) answers but it didn't work.
2. Normal telegram bots cannot send videos larger than 50 mb. For this, you need to create a telegram bot local server and run the bot on this local server. Is there an easier way?

```
# simple code 
# exeption: age restricted
from pytube import YouTube

url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9ezpAUvMC8&pp=ygUPbG92ZSB5b3VyIHZvaWNl'

yt=YouTube(url,use_oauth=True,allow_oauth_cache=True)
print(yt.age_restricted)

print(yt.streams)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your site-packages:
**C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\innertube.py** line **223**
change `client='ANDROID_MUSIC'` to `client='ANDROID'`

```
def __init__(self, client='ANDROID', use_oauth=False, allow_cache=True):
```

```
from pytube import YouTube
url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9ezpAUvMC8&pp=ygUPbG92ZSB5b3VyIHZvaWNl'

yt=YouTube(url,use_oauth=True,allow_oauth_cache=True)
print(yt.age_restricted)
stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
stream.download()
```